# How to manage URLs in PHP

Tags: php, url, frameworks

I have urls like:

`example.com/category?id=5,`

but I want this url look like

`example.com/category/category_name`.

I use pure php without any framework.
Can you please suggest me any way to do it..?

Comment: Basically, you need to change your urls to look like that. There is no magic bullet that can just know that category_id = 5 is the same as eg toys without you writing code to do that, especially as you have not used any framework

Answer (score 0):

This is something you should try to solve with your webserver, it's not really an PHP question. For Apache, the mechanism is called modRewrite.

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html should be an easy starter.

Comment: Oddly, it seems to me that PHP users are the only group where the majority of them lean on mod_rewrite to solve this. Everything else I've looked at leans on the language for it. I'm particularly fond of [Catalyst actions](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Catalyst-Manual-5.9007/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Intro.pod#Actions) as a solution to this.

Comment: @Quentin He specifically said he had a prior existing codebase that does not use a framework. So he gets the solution that does not need adding a framework layer ;)

Comment: You don't need a framework layer to parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 0):

If under Apache, use some .htacces mechanism.

Anyway your beautified url should contain some reliable data as the category id, not only the category (sluggified) name.

Let's say you want an url like :

```
example.com/category/category_name/id
```

In your .htaccess you'll use a rule like :

```
RewriteRule   ^example.com/category/([a-z0-9\-]+)/(\d+)$ /example.com/category?id=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Check your web sertver documentation for details explanations

Answer (score 0):

look into using mod rewrite as part of apache. You will have a .htaccess file in the root of the web server (if not create 1 and then add the rules you need)
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

there is a site that you can provide a url from a page on your site and it will create the mod rewrite code for you

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/